# Reset timed task in a correct way

Tags: java

I have a timedtask, launched by a timer with startAtFixedInterval, interval is long.
Timed task's job is to check for changes on a web site.

I'd like to allow the user to manually restart the task in the middle of the interval, in order to obtain the new result without waiting for the end of the interval.
I can't see any reset() method so I guess I'd have to stop and restart the taks, am I right?
Or there IS actually a way/best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class there's `cancel()` method. It cancels current timer task. And when current timer task has been cancelled launch a new one.

Comment: "Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks. Does not interfere with a currently executing task (if it exists). Once a timer has been terminated, its execution thread terminates gracefully, and no more tasks may be scheduled on it." so I lost the scheduling which is not what I want.

Comment: Have several Timers, one for each task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ScheduledExecutorService`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Runnable command = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("I am done..");              
        }
    };

    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(command, 1000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}
```

Comment: Whenever you want to stop call `shutdown()` and get the executor to schedule again.